# redux middleware -> intercept/block/transform?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware

we're running a SPA. dispatched actions (not components) are auth-based.

is it possible to intercept and transform dispatched actions?

i.e.

```
dispatch({
    type: 'FOO',
    payload: { some: value }
})

function magicMiddleware(action) => decide if authorized. 
if no...

dispatch({
    type: 'BAR',
    payload: { new: value }
})

else continue
```

note that 'FOO' should never hit a reducer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely one of the intended use cases for middleware.  Any middleware can inspect and modify any action going through the pipeline before it reaches the reducers, and even prevent an action from continuing on.

You may want to read through the [Middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) page in the Redux docs, as well as the articles in the [Redux Middleware](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-middleware.md) category in my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).  Those should give you a better idea how middleware work, and how you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let that action hit the reducer and ignore it there?
(best option IMO)

```
switch (action.type) {
  case SOMETHING_NOT_FOO:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      whatever other new object here...
  })
  default:
    return state
}
```

If you do this through your middleware, you'd need to decide if you want to send that action to the reducer or not:

```
function yourMiddleware(nextDispatch) {
  return function(action) {
    // do stuff
    if (action.type !== 'FOO') {
      return nextDispatch(action);
    } else {
      return nextDispatch({type: 'dummy'}); // need to send an action 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: While it's certainly possible, there are better ways to handle such actions than send them through a reducer which won't update any state

Comment: why put logic in the reducer that involves doing nothing to create new state? furthermore, permissions-based actions also means having to stop some actions from reaching the reducer (transforming the action into a login flow rather than the originally intended one)

Comment: @AnthonyChung, you're actually not putting any logic, you're ignoring an action. The second option, I don't like it, but you could probably make it work depending on what position you put the middleware in, like last.

Comment: @Ignacio if I am ignoring the action, I'm returning state. What if I want to dispatch another action (like bring up a login modal) as a result? Not sure how else I'd be able to have the user enter a new flow

Comment: Hi, @AnthonyChung, I think it'd be nice if you could explain with more detail what you're trying to achieve. Maybe more specific.